# Create a box plot with one hot encoding column parameters

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe of predicted and actual values along with the season

```
print(df)
```

```
     actuals  predicted  winter  spring  summer  fall
0         36  44.407143       1       0       0     0
1         23  44.092857       1       0       0     0
2         61  65.435714       1       0       0     0
3         32  39.250000       1       0       0     0
4         50  50.007143       1       0       0     0
..       ...        ...     ...     ...     ...   ...
220       11  23.739286       0       1       0     0
221        5  27.173129       0       1       0     0
222        4  22.335714       0       1       0     0
223       11  98.157143       0       1       0     0
224       27  61.550000       0       1       0     0
```

I've browsed many sites with documentation for box plots with pandas, seaborn and matplotlib but they don't seem to do me any justice in this case.

How can I create a box plot with this data where the `x` values are the seasons (`winter`, `spring`, `summer`, `fall`) and the `y` values are the `actuals` and `predicted`?

Heres an example of something I'm trying to create:

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to @BigBen, I have the this

```
# reverse one-hot encoding
df['season'] = (df.iloc[:, 2:] == 1).idxmax(1)

# actuals and predicted to one column
df = df.melt(id_vars ='season', value_vars=['actuals', 'predicted'])

sn.boxplot(x='season', y='value', hue='variable', data=df, palette="Set3")
```

[image]

However, the plot looks really congested with the thick grey borders surrounding the boxes, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some reshaping and then using [`sns.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) with `hue` should work:

```
# reverse one-hot encoding
df['season'] = (df.iloc[:, 2:] == 1).idxmax(1)

# actuals and predicted to one column
df = df.melt(id_vars ='season', value_vars=['actuals', 'predicted'])

sns.boxplot(x='season', y='value', hue='variable', data=df, palette="Set3")
```

Output:

[image]

You can add more meaningful column names using `var_name` and `value_name` when `melt`ing.

Comment: Thank you! My plot is exactly how I wanted minus the thick borders. Please see the edit

Comment: Try changing the `linewidth` when `boxplot`ting. Increasing the size of the figure might also be helpful.

Comment: I want to see more values in my box plot so I tried using `set_yscale('log')` but it gives me an error

Comment: I thought about that option as well. Did you do `ax = sns.boxplot(....)` and then `ax.set_yscale('log')`?

Comment: Yea I tried that `AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'set_yscale'`

Comment: `sns.boxplot` returns a matplotlib `Axes`, not sure where you're getting a `Text` object.

Comment: Thats funny, because I just used `plt.yscale('log')` and it worked

Comment: Matplotlib has an object-oriented interface... `plt.yscale` is the pyplot interface (state-based). `ax.set_yscale` is the former, and is generally preferred to the latter (see [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html)).